# CheckBox in Nativescript (ios and Android)

Tags: javascript, listview, nativescript

What is the best way to create checkbox in Nativescript with javascript?

I know if I use checkbox it's only for Android, and I have problems with the switches. So I will like use images to reproduce a checkbox.

I have this XML

```
<ListView items="{{ whishList }}">
        <ListView.itemTemplate>
            <GridLayout class="listes" columns="auto,*,30">
                <Image id="id_check" src="res://selectoff" tap="CheckList"/>
                <Label id="id_wishlist" text="{{ id_wishlist }}"/>
            </GridLayout>
        </ListView.itemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

If I tap the image, I would Like to change the image of item.
And with JS I need to change the image, but this changes only the last item:

```
exports.CheckList = function(args){var customControl = args.object;
  customControl.bindingContext = whishList;
  var checkID = customControl.parent.parent.getViewById("id_check");
  checkID.src ="res://selecton";
}
```

Comment: Or you could use the plugin https://github.com/bradmartin/nativescript-checkbox that uses the native android checkbox and an iOS cocoapod then no need to replace images to mimic a checkbox. I think what you need to do is get the index and then replace the Image at the index in the listviews `items`. The issue with that might be when you recycle the items in the list view - so you likely need to assign dynamic ids to the items inside the `itemTemplate` so that they're correct when the views are coming in/out of the view

Comment: Thanks. The plugin have errors, I can't call the itemTap, and for JS the property checked always send false.

Comment: The property shouldn't always be false with the plugin. It works fine in the demo app of the plugin. Not sure what you've tried so can't help much. As for the itemTap - there are ways to do what you want for sure. Just not sure exactly what you're after right now.

Comment: Yes, It was an error for my part. The plugin is good. The tap problem is with Android, but the solution is set focusable to false. Thanks @Brad Martin

Comment: I moved your solution to a community wiki

Answer (score 0):

My solution is the following

```
var customControl = args.object;
var checkID = customControl.parent.getViewById("id_check");
checkID.src ="res://checkon";
```

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

The checkbox plugin described by @Brad Martin [github.com/bradmartin/nativescript-checkbox](https://github.com/bradmartin/nativescript-checkbox) works, the problem is in the itemtap, if this is in a list-view with others components.

For example:
If we would like the itemTap for each element, with the checkbox is not possible, the solution is set focusable to false.

```
exports.CheckLoaded=function(args) {
    // This is only an issue in Android
    if (app.android) {
        var ChBox= args.object;
        ChBox.android.setFocusable(false);
    }
}
```